# Select values from C# KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

Code:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string[]>>();
list .Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string[]>(1, new string[] { "1", "One"}));
list .Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string[]>(2, new string[] { "2", "Two"}));
list .Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string[]>(3, new string[] { "3", "Three"}));
list .Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string[]>(4, new string[] { "4", "Four"}));
```

Need to select only the values from this list of KeyValuePairs and build an array. I tried this.

```
var values = list.Select(v => v.Value.ToList()).ToArray();
```

Expecting a `string[]` like this.

```
{"1", "One", "2", "Two", "3", "Three", "4", "Four"}
```

But it returns a `List<string>[]` like this

```
{{"1", "One"}, {"2", "Two"}, {"3", "Three"}, {"4", "Four"}}
```

Also tried

```
var values = list.Select(v => v.Value.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

But it returns `string[][]`. I can convert the `string[][]` to `string[]` but I want to do it directly using Linq.

I need to pass the expected array to another method. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like:

```
var values = list.SelectMany(v => v.Value).ToArray();
```

[SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and
>   **flattens** the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SelectMany](http://www.dotnetperls.com/selectmany)

```
 var values = list.SelectMany(v => v.Value).ToArray();
```